# Extra icon by share button

Tags: share-menu

I was playing around with Android's "share" feature and now I've got this extra icon which I really don't like and I can't figure out how to make it go away.

The icon is to the right of the share button and has the icon of the app that I was sharing to. In the screenshot below it shows as the Gmail icon.

http://i1383.photobucket.com/albums/ah291/Micheal98/Screenshot_2015-04-01-11-17-14_zpskm0lit2i.png

Comment: Upload an image imgur or any other image upload sites and share link here.

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Comment: Did you last share to Gmail? Looks to me like it's a "shortcut" to the last app shared to. Sharing to any other app will probably replace it by that app's icon. And most likely the only way to completely get rid of it is a reboot.

Comment: Yes I was trying it with Gmail. But I don't want to replace it with another icon; I want to get rid of it completely. And rebooting the phone didn't get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of it by going to the app's "App Info" page and tapping the "Clear Data" button. Obviously that won't work if you want to keep any of the app's other data but in my case I was willing to sacrifice the thumbnail cache to get rid of the extra icon.

The strange thing is that I remember trying that before I asked this question but I guess not.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I cannot use the comment system yet, but I know what you're referring to.  Once you access the "share" feature, it automatically provides a "shortcut" to the last app you tried to "share" with.  I actually find it a pretty convenient feature.  I don't think you can get rid of it (unless you find a custom gallery or something).  If you share your photos with anybody, I'd use the most-oft used app to share with, and just leave it there. i.e. messaging / facebook / etc.

Comment: I don't use the sharing feature. I was just messing around, but I want to get rid of the extra icon because it looks ugly. I use the gallery app a lot and I don't want that icon there every time I use it.

Comment: I've been unable to find anything that would help you get rid of it.  The only thing I can think of would be to reset your phone to default (which I'm sure you don't want) and never touch the share option again.

Comment: That sounds kind of ridiculous - you would think there would be some kind of "clear data" or "clear cache" or "clear history" option that would remove that.

Comment: What version of android are you using?

Comment: @MichealJohnson as Dithanial said which version you are using as in 5.0 its not there.

Comment: I'm using Android version 4.1.